# Any limitation to use SqliteDB to get approval of IOS app store deployment which is developed using Phonegap..?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I was planning to use localStorage in my application to store some data now i have realized that it is not persistent. So I am going to use SQLite DB.

I know that ,  data stored in localStorage does not get backed up to iCloud and thus resulting in Apple rejecting your app for voilating the Data Storage Guidelines so i am using the below  config settings for localStorage

```
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
```

Before starting to use SQLite , I want to know that, is there any limitation to use SQLite DB in IOS appstore deployment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LocalStorage is persistent as long as you not remove the application from your device. No option to safe data does store data longer than that. If you want to store data over the lifetime of an app use icloud.

Comment: @Sithys
 With Android > 5 I noticed that localStorage is cleared when one closes the app via task manager.